# I am implementing AWS instance scheduler, if I want to keep an instance/environment up although it's scheduled to go down what can I do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda, aws-lambda

I have implemented AWS instance scheduler with a schedule that starts an EC2-instance at 9:00am in the morning and shuts it down at 5:00pm.

I have a specific requirement from dev team where if they are working on an instance at 4:55pm that particular instance should skip schedule and not go down at 5:00pm. What can be the simplest way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, simplest way is to use Tags on EC2 instances.
Keep a tag to act as a flag and use it to include/exclude the instance for scheduling.

Ex:
AutoStartStop: True

In the scheduler, use CLIs/APIs to identify the list of instances having a filter on this tag with value as True to start or stop instances

The users can be allowed to update the tags based on their needs

Hope this helps !!